# Remove member of all groups active directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have 2 server in my company one is Us.local(<--main domain) and 2nd is India.local
we get the bulk termination in our india.local domain and I want to remove all AD groups from the tab. I am using the below mentioned script to remove all members of groups.

Note: There is no issue with users account we can disable and remove groups manually

```
$users= import-CSv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\DisableUsers.csv

$totalcount  = $users.Count
write-host $totalcount

$currentCount = 1

Foreach ($u in $users)
{
#Remove members from DL (AD)
Get-ADUser -Server:"addc45.india.local" $u.UserID -Properties MemberOf | Select -Expand MemberOf | %{Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -member $u.UserID -Confirm:$false }

Write-host "Disabled" $u.UserID $currentCount "/" $totalcount

$currentCount++
}
```

I am getting the below mentioned error every time I use powershell.

```
Remove-ADGroupMember : A referral was returned from the server
At line:15 char:125
+ ... emberOf | %{Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -member $u.UserID -Confirm:$false ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (CN=VDI-IN-EQ-SV...health,DC=local:ADGroup) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADReferralException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8235,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
 
Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'IN100040' under: 'DC=US,DC=local'.
At line:15 char:125
+ ... emberOf | %{Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -member $u.UserID -Confirm:$false ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (IN100040:ADPrincipal) [Remove-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetADGroupMember.ValidateMembersParameter,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADGroupMember
```

Comment: `-Server:"addc45.india.local"` --> `-Server "addc45.india.local"`

Comment: it is not working showing same error

Comment: You also need to set that parameter on the `Remove-ADGroupMember` of course, otherwise it will connect to the DC in your domain which apparently is not in India. `Remove-ADGroupMember $_ -Server "addc45.india.local" -Members $u.UserID -Confirm:$false`. Chances are that you will also need the `-Credential` parameter to give you permissions to do that operation

Comment: not working it is giving the same error brother